How can I make a button lead to another page via href?
<a href="#" className="btn btn-brand me-2">Get Started</a>

I have this button which I want to link to another page
const Signup = () => {.....}
export default Signup;

This is the function builder and export skeletal code for a component which will be the signup/login page for an app. It's the one I wish to link to via the button above.
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Hero />
      <About />
      <Pricing />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

Here's my app.js' function with the different components of my welcome page. Right now, I want the welcome page to act separate, but a couple of buttons on the welcome page should lead to the signup page.
Thanks!

What should the url of the signup page be?

I don't have a specific url as of right now, but I was thinking it could be related to the exported content so 'signup...' Ideally, I want it to be a subdomain of the other site in the end. As far as domains, I don't have one yet but I'd really appreciate if you could explain the process of how to accomplish this.

Then just change it to <a href="signup" … and you're done

Install react-router-dom if not installed then go through the below code.
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './Navbar'; // Adjust paths according to your file structure
import Hero from './Hero';
import About from './About';
import Pricing from './Pricing';
import Footer from './Footer';
import Signup from './Signup'; // Adjust path according to where your Signup component is located

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Hero />
        <About />
        <Pricing />
        <footer>
          {/* Your footer content */}
        </footer>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            {/* Content for the welcome page goes here */}
            <button onClick={() => window.location.href="/signup"}>Get Started</button>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/signup">
            <Signup />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;


Please explain how this wall-of-code actually addresses the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers.

Why use <button onClick={() => window.location.href="/signup"}> instead of a normal <a> hyperlink that the OP already has?

react it self is not reliable when it comes to routing
you need to install react-router-dom the same way you installed react via (npm ,yarn,etc..)
once you get it installed you need to wrap your App component like this in the index file
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>

     <App />

  </BrowserRouter>,
);

now at you App component you need to define something look like this under you return statement
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/sign-up" element={<Signup />} />
    <Route path="/sign-in" element={<Signin />} />
  </Routes>

Routes is the wrapper for all the Route you might have
path is the path after the url,
element is pointing to the component you want to render at this path
lets assume you have button lead to /any-path
you would import Link Component from react-router-dom
then use it like this
<Link to="/sign-up">Signup</Link>

Link is woking as <a href=""></a>
Right now you should try to localhost:port/sign-up, Signup Component should be displayed if it has jsx returned like any regular component
i would recommend React-router-dom Article it would help after then
